# if skolem($\alpha$) is valid then $\alpha$ is valid

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I am trying to prove the following claim:
let $sk(\alpha)$ be the sentence received from the skolemization of a given sentence $\alpha$.
**Prove** : $\vDash sk(\alpha) \implies \vDash \alpha$

I tried to prove an equivalent claim : $\nvDash a \implies \nvDash sk(\alpha)$
but I had one problem in the proof of this claim : can I say the following :

Lets assume $\alpha$ is not valid **but** it is satisfied by some structure $\\M$. then from the definition of skolemization we know that $sk(\alpha)$ is satisfied by some other structure M'.
In addition , there exists another structure $\hat{M}$ s.t $\hat{M}\nvDash \alpha$ which implies that $\hat{M} \vDash \neg{\alpha}$ . Therefore , $sk(\neg\alpha)$ is satisfied by some structure $M_1$. **Does it say that $M_1$ satisfy $\neg sk(\alpha)$?**
If it does, how can i prove it?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you share some details about how your "Skolemization" works? There are slight differences between authors in precisely what that means.

Comment: Doesn't it follow from the validity of $sk(\alpha)\to\alpha$?

Comment: @bof: It is not entirely trivial to make that into semantic argument, because $\operatorname{sk}(\alpha)$ and $\operatorname \alpha$ are formulas in different languages, so the class of structures that $\vDash\operatorname{sk}(\alpha)$ and $\vDash \alpha$ implicitly quantify over are not the same.

Comment: @HenningMakholm It *seems* trivial enough. Any structure for the language of $\alpha$ can be expanded to a structure for the language of $sk(\alpha)$, e.g., just make the Skolem functions constants. But it's been a *very* long time since I was in a logic class.

Comment: @bof: I think it is doable; I just wouldn't call it "trivial". But perhaps it is. (The problems I thought I saw would be harder if we were going to construct a syntactic argument instead).,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO; saying that $\nvDash \alpha$ means that there is **at least one** structure $\mathcal M$ such that $\mathcal M \nvDash \alpha$.

**Hint**

Assume that $\alpha$ is $\forall x \exists y \phi(x,y)$; thus its "skolemization" must be : $sk(\alpha) := \forall x \phi(x,f(x))$.

From $\nvDash \alpha$ we have that, for some $\mathcal M$, with domain $M=|\mathcal M|$, we have some $a \in M$ such that $\mathcal M \nvDash \exists y \phi(x,y)[a]$ [intuitively, if $\forall x\psi(x)$ is not *true* in $\mathcal M$, we have that, for some "value" $a$ of $x$, $\psi$ does not hold of $a$].

But $\mathcal M \nvDash \exists y \phi(x,y)[a]$ means that for every $b \in M$ : $\mathcal M \nvDash \phi(x,y)[a,b]$.

This means that we have "no way" to define a function $f^M : M \to M$ such that : $f^M(a)$ satisfy in $\mathcal M$ : $\phi(x,y)[a,f^M(a)]$, and this implies that $\mathcal M \nvDash \forall x \phi(x,f(x))$.

Thus, having found a structure $\mathcal M$ such that $\mathcal M \nvDash \forall x \phi(x,f(x))$, we conclude with :

> $\nvDash sk(\alpha)$.